# Range returns an empty cell, although the referenced cell contains data

Tags: excel, vba

My script opens an external .xls file and reads it. On a particular page, I have troubles with reading some specific cells - even if directly referenced, they return as "Empty".

Essentially, it looks something like this:

```
MsgBox Workbooks.Open("d:\file.xls").Worksheets("Page 11").Range("E34").Value
```

The message box pops up empty, when it should display a numeric value in that cell. Also, if I run the script from the start unobstructed, it may successfully pass E34 but will break on next column. Debugger says that several other columns on that same page are empty when they are not.

The only thing that I can think of is some columns are merged, but I checked that I'm referencing the right cells.

Edit: I tried to run `MsgBox Worksheets("Page 11").Range("E34").Value` from the file itself, it also popped up empty.

Here's a visualization of relevant zone:

[image]

Comment: Please can you input some visualization of how your cells look?

Comment: @JvdV there you go

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary and going by just that little bit of code it should work. You sure you refer to the right File/Worksheet/Cell? Btw, `MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("'D:\[file.xls]Page 11'!R34C5")` would make you don't have to open your file. But probably doesn't solve your issue

Comment: @JvdV okay, nevermind, it's merged cells. There're invisible columns D and I that mess up everything

Comment: Yup merged cells are vbas worst nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

There're invisible columns D and I that mess up everything